MailChimp query parameter 'since' is not working
I am trying to get all email activity since some date but it is giving me data from months before the since date as well, here is my code:
$queryParams = array(
        'fields' => null,
        'exclude_fields' => 'emails.list_is_active,emails.email_id,emails.email_address,emails._links,_links',
        'count' => 500,
        'offset' => 0,
        'since' => '2024-11-15T15:41:36+00:00'
    );

$result = $client->reports->getEmailActivityForCampaign(
            $campaignID,
            $queryParams['fields'],
            $queryParams['exclude_fields'],
            $queryParams['count'],
            $queryParams['offset'],
            $queryParams['since']
        );

The resulting array has dates from September 2024 in it.
You can find the documentation here
Am I missing something?
I tried setting 'since' => '2025-11-15T15:41:36+00:00' just for the heck of it and it still gave me records from this year.
All the other query parameters are working fine.

Not sure we can fix a bug inside the mailchimp API, or even in their PHP client - probably needs a support request to mailchimp. We can help you with your code, but I can't see any obvious issues with that.
